# How to fix Unity expected compiler error?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I've been making an escape room game, but the FPSCounter Script has been made 2 compiler errors:
[click here to view compiler errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGN0p.png)

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace StandardAssets.Utility
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (UI.Text))]
    public class FPSCounter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        const float fpsMeasurePeriod = 0.5f;
        private int m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
        private float m_FpsNextPeriod = 0;
        private int m_CurrentFps;
        const string display = "{0} FPS";
        private UI.Text m_UI.Text;


        private void Start()
        {
            m_FpsNextPeriod = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + fpsMeasurePeriod;
            m_UI.Text = GetComponent<UI.Text>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            // measure average frames per second
            m_FpsAccumulator++;
            if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup > m_FpsNextPeriod)
            {
                m_CurrentFps = (int) (m_FpsAccumulator/fpsMeasurePeriod);
                m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
                m_FpsNextPeriod += fpsMeasurePeriod;
                m_UI.Text.text = string.Format(display, m_CurrentFps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of times, but it creates more errors.
For example, I put an ( at the start of UI.Text, and it creates total of 8 compiler errors.
Anyone give me the code that fix these errors?

Comment: Nope. This is *not* java

Comment: Ohhh. But the File Explorer said it was Java. But please help me and fix the code!